# Kendo UI Angular2 NumericTextBox not showing updated value till it is focused

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

In Kendo NumericTextBox if the value is updated on the component for e.x. in the Plunkr I have a interval trigger to increase value every 2 seconds, the updated value is visible on NumericTextBox only when the textbox is in focus. As per Angular2 data-binding any expression like [value]="numberValue" should hook for changes to "numberValue" and update it's value.

[Plunkr for issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/omlefk6zfhHc4lB3yXzt?p=preview)

```
`http://plnkr.co/edit/omlefk6zfhHc4lB3yXzt?p=preview`
```

Comment: Are you using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your app?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Please open a new issue in the [Kendo Angular repo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues).

Comment: In the mean time you can use [(ngModel)] instead of [value]

Comment: [(ngModel)] will not solve my issue. I have the case where on update of one field I want to update the numeric textbox value.